# Prevent Multiple Submit Button Clicks Without Using JavaScript or JQuery in Web App?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, web-applications, data-entry

My simple web-app is as follows:  I have a JSP form (`MyForm.JSP`) that takes user input and passes it to my first servlet (`"/myfirstservlet"`).

This servlet handles the SQL insert of the user input values into my `Fruits` table and then redirects the user to my results servlet (`"/results"`).

My results servlet then checks for the an `"ADD"` parameter and if "true" (i.e. it equals `"success"`) it finally redirects the user to my Results JSP (`Results.JSP`) which is stored inside the path:  `WEB-INF/MyFolder/Results.jsp`.

My JSP form (`MyForm.JSP`) is also stored inside the path:  `WEB-INF/MyFolder/MyForm.jsp`

I did this way to prevent the user from re-submitting the form by clicking the refresh button on the Results JSP page so as to avoid having multiple entries of the same data that was just previously entered into the database.

My issue now is:  How do I prevent the user from clicking the submit button **multiple** times on my form (`MyForm.JSP`) thereby preventing multiple rows of the same data getting entered into my database **WITHOUT** using JavaScript or JQuery?

Basically, I want to validate in my server, not client-side, that the form has been submitted only ONCE.

My JSP form (`MyForm.JSP`):

```
<form action="myfirstservlet" do="POST">
   <input type="text" name="fruit"><br>
   <input type="text" name="color"><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

My first servlet (`"/myfirstservlet"`):

```
protected void doPost(...){
   String fruit = request.getParameter("fruit");
   String color = request.getParameter("color");

   String sql = "INSERT INTO fruits (fruit, color) VALUES" + "(\"" + fruit +  "\", \""  + color +  "\");";

   utilitySQL.sqlInsert(sql); // My utility class that handles sql inserts

   response.sendRedirect("results?ADD=SUCCESS");
}
```

My results servlet (`"/results"`):

```
protected void doPost(...){

   response.setContentType("text/html");    

   if (request.getParameter("ADD").equals("SUCCESS"))
      request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/MyFolder/Results.jsp").forward(request, response);

}
```

My Results JSP (`Results.JSP`):

```
<body>
<h1>Results JSP</h1>


  //Reads data from MySQL database and prints it as an Array List.

</body>
```

**EDIT:**  Fixed my prepared statemnt in my first servlet:

```
protected void doPost(...){


       String fruit = request.getParameter("fruit");
       String color = request.getParameter("color");

       try 
        {
            String sql2 = "INSERT INTO practice (fruit, color) VALUES (?, ?);";
            Connection connect = SQLHelperClass.connectOnly();
            PreparedStatement pstmt;
            pstmt = connect.prepareStatement(sql2);
            pstmt.setString(1, fruit);
            pstmt.setString(2, color);

            pstmt.execute();

            response.sendRedirect("results?ADD=success");
        } 

        catch (SQLException e) 
        {           
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Comment: do you consider `<input type="submit" onclick="this.disabled=true" value="Submit">` javascript?

Comment: I've read that it's better practice to validate in the server

Comment: ok but can you tell me what you are validating?

Comment: Whether the form with the user input data has been received by the server, and if true then prevent the other multiple submit clicks coming from the form with the same data.  Basically, it's to ensure that only one row is inserted into the database at a time per each form filled and submitted.

Comment: Generally when creating a web form, it is good practice to guide user behavior by guiding them through the desired user experience. Disabling the button or displaying a process overlay are common methods to avoid multiple submits. If you desire to do this server side, think about if you would want the backend api to limit multiple `POST` requests? If so, the DB integrity or rate limiting might be good options.

Comment: That's true.  But I also want to guard against more experienced and potentially malicious users (i.e. hackers) who will know the ins-and-outs and around web-apps such as by simply disabling JavaScript on their browsers.

Comment: you say that but you do `String sql = "INSERT INTO fruits (fruit, color) VALUES" + "(\"" + fruit +  "\", \""  + color +  "\");";` ... https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: @Charles Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had an id field for a logged in user, this would be easier because you could just create a table for the results a specific user has submitted and before entering it into the fruits table, check whether the user has already submitted the same data.

From the looks of it, it doesn't look like you have any user identification fields, so a hacky way of preventing duplicates might be to make use of sessions.

A session is unique to the user who is currently using your application/website. Each person who visits your website/application gets their own unique session id. (they are stored as a cookie)

So for example:

```
protected void doPost(...){
   String fruit = request.getParameter("fruit");
   String color = request.getParameter("color");

   //unless you wanna complicate things, i would create a string out of the two parameters and store it into an arraylist of strings
   String value = fruit+color; 

   HttpSession session = (request.getSession()); //get session
   if(null == session.getAttribute("duplicates")){ //if session variable empty then we know that user has not submitted anything yet so we let them insert into db

     insertFruit(fruit,color); //add to db

     ArrayList<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>(); //create arraylist
     duplicates.add(value); //add our unique value
     session.setAttribute("duplicates", duplicates); //set as session variable

    }else{
     //here the session variable is not empty so that means the user has already submitted something so lets check the arraylist and make sure the value does not already exist

     ArrayList<String> duplicates = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("duplicates");

     if(!duplicates.contains(value)){
      //if arraylist does not contain the same value, then it's safe to add
       insertFruit(fruit,color); //add to db

      //forgot this part
      duplicates.add(value);
      session.setAttribute("duplicates", duplicates); //update the variable
     }


    }


   response.sendRedirect("results?ADD=SUCCESS");
}

public void insertFruit(String fruit, String color){

       try(Connection connect = SQLHelperClass.connectOnly()){
         PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO practice (fruit, color) VALUES (?, ?);");

        pst.setString(1, fruit);
        pst.setString(2, color);

        pst.executeUpdate();

          }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

}
```

**EDIT 1:**

In regards to the comment about not repeating the database operation for each servlet. You need to separate out the logic. The way people normally do it is by creating a seperate class for all your database operations.

For example...

create a class called `FruitDao`, here you keep all your fruit related database operations

public class FruitDao{

```
public void insertFruit(String fruit, String color){

       try(Connection connect = SQLHelperClass.connectOnly()){
         PreparedStatement pst = connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO practice (fruit, color) VALUES (?, ?);");

        pst.setString(1, fruit);
        pst.setString(2, color);

        pst.executeUpdate();

          }catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

}
```

To call this from your servlet just do:

```
protected void doPost(...){
   FruitDao fdao = new FruitDao(); // get the db class for fruits
   String fruit = request.getParameter("fruit");
   String color = request.getParameter("color");

   //unless you wanna complicate things, i would create a string out of the two parameters and store it into an arraylist of strings
   String value = fruit+color; 

   HttpSession session = (request.getSession()); //get session
   if(null == session.getAttribute("duplicates")){ //if session variable empty then we know that user has not submitted anything yet so we let them insert into db

     fdao.insertFruit(fruit,color); //add to db

     ArrayList<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>(); //create arraylist
     duplicates.add(value); //add our unique value
     session.setAttribute("duplicates", duplicates); //set as session variable

    }else{
     //here the session variable is not empty so that means the user has already submitted something so lets check the arraylist and make sure the value does not already exist

     ArrayList<String> duplicates = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("duplicates");

     if(!duplicates.contains(value)){
      //if arraylist does not contain the same value, then it's safe to add
        fdao.insertFruit(fruit,color); //add to db

      //forgot this part
      duplicates.add(value);
      session.setAttribute("duplicates", duplicates); //update the variable
     }


    }


   response.sendRedirect("results?ADD=SUCCESS");
}
```

Comment: The caveat here is that if the user deletes their ssid cookie, they will be able to submit the same data

Comment: also check out the insertFruit method, that's how you should make connections to your databse. By wrapping it in a try catch block, it will automatically close the connection for you.

Comment: The session.setAttributes() requires an object as a second parameter.

Comment: I have another external class for my db connection SQLHelperClass which has a method connectOnly() that returns a Connect object.  Is this way not ideal than rather repeatedly writing it for each servlet I have?

Comment: @JaeBin `setAttribute` not `setAttributes`

Comment: yeah that's how you're supposed to do it. Create a separate connection class which you use everytime you want to get the connection. But what you're doing wrong here is doing your database operations in the servlet itself. You're supposed to seperate the logic. So for example check my edit in 1 minute.

Comment: `session.setAttribute()` also requires an object as a second parameter according to Eclipse.

Comment: @JaeBin ah oops forgot to add the second parameter to the session variable...
`session.setAttribute("duplicates", duplicates);`

Comment: @JaeBin check the updated answer, i give you an example there on how to separate the db logic from the servlet

Comment: And if I want to get the attribute in my Results servlet I just do `session.getAttribute(duplicates)` right?  And then determine if it's null or not?

Comment: @JaeBin exactly, but before getting the values from it.. you should check if it is null. Otherwise you will get a nullpointer exception if it is null.

Comment: @JaeBin sorry lol, forgot one last thing that you need in order to make it work.. inside the if(!duplicates.contains).. you need to add the value to the session variable and update it... check edited answer. Let me know when you got it working

Comment: Hi again, I realized you are using an ArrayList<String> to compare values and the duplicates.  would this still work if I changed the Array<String> to just String and so duplicates will become `duplicates = duplicates + values`?

Comment: @JaeBin uhmm yes i guess it would work like that too. But why would you want to do that?

Comment: Btw, `String duplicates = duplicates + values` is the same thing as `String duplicates += values`

Comment: It's still duplicating entries for me when I initially start up my server (Tomcat) but only on the first submit try, when I press the submit button multiple times before the Result page loads.  And then I check MySQL db and all the duplicated entries are there.  On subsequent tries after the first try, it doesn't duplicate anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182048/discussion-between-jonathan-laliberte-and-jae-bin).